# Can we declare private constructor in abstract class? When this situation occurs?

Tags: java

Need to know can we declare private construct in abstract class and how to access it in Java.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's an `abstract` class doesn't make a difference. A `private` constructor can only be accessed from within the class in which it is defined.

For example, it could be accessed from other constructors of that same class, using `this()`.

Comment: Or indeed from a subclass constructor that shares the same top-level class.